# SQL Server Management Studio alternatives to browse/edit tables and run queries

Tags: sql-server

I was wondering if there are any alternatives to Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio?

Not there's anything wrong with SSMS, but sometimes it just seem too big an application where all I want todo is browse/edit tables and run queries.

Comment: Is there not a command prompt utility for this like mysql has?

Comment: @Kevin: check osql and sqlcmd

Comment: @jerhewet : try SQL Database Studio - far better than smss and is around 6MB large (installation file) http://sqldatabasestudio.com/

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I've started using [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). In addition to being more lightweight than SSMS, you can also practice writing LINQ queries- way more fun than boring old TSQL!

Comment: I strongly feel that we can't edit tables and can't run queries with hints using LINQ

Comment: No intellisense in free version

Comment: Hopefully it's less horrifically, unacceptably buggy than SSMS as well. The amount of crashes I get in SSMS is ridic, even with fresh reinstalls of newer versions. May be specific to my machine but not cool nonetheless

Comment: @KyleVassella Weird! I very seldom get SSMS to crash, and I do power stuff with it every day - v 17.9.1 & 18.4

Answer (score 20):

[TOAD for MS SQL](http://toadworld.com/) looks pretty good.  I've never used it personally but I have used Quest's other products and they're solid.

Comment: Hmm, I just downloaded their trial and it throws really bizarre exceptions all over the place... has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: As of today the version(5.0.2.612) of TOAD for MS SQL Server it just what I was looking for. It is so much better than MS Management Studio 2008.

Comment: I've used Toad and I find it as bloated as MS SQL

Comment: If you are looking to add some nice features to SSMS then go grab SSSM Tools Pack (free) which adds many usefull features to SSMS.

Comment: The toad products are bittersweet.  They have amazing features (sortable columns and basic aggregation in the output grid, db diagramming) but they. are. buggy.   Dmitri hit it on the nose with the wild exceptions and it's three years since he sent it.  Hopefully the purchase by Dell and the focus on the multipurpose Toad Data Point will clean up a potentially amazing piece of software.

Comment: Be aware that SMSS tools pack is not free for SMSS 2012 and higher.

Answer (score 19):

Seems that no one mentioned [Query Express](http://www.albahari.com/queryexpress.aspx) (http://www.albahari.com/queryexpress.aspx) and a fork [Query ExPlus](http://sourceforge.net/projects/queryexplus/) (also link at the bottom of http://www.albahari.com/queryexpress.aspx)

BTW. First URL is the home page of Joseph Albahari who is the author of LINQPad (check out this killer tool)

Comment: Also you can have a look at Heidi SQL (OSS, very nice), DBSourceTools (OSS software hosted at codeplex.com, source control centric), SQuirrel SQL (OSS written in Java). Additionally SQL Assistant (not an IDE, but still interresting) is a sort of a run querries everywhere (even in Notepad) util with lots of nice features (paid though).

Answer (score 19):

[Database .NET](http://fishcodelib.com/Database.htm)

Comment: Simple, fast to download, no installation required,free for personal use and it does more then simple editing. This is a really good choice.

Comment: I just gave it a quick try and I must say it looks just great!

Comment: I am giving it a try and it's not a bad product. Probably it needs improvements but it's well done and a good alternative to SQL Manager

Comment: This is great, and free. The paid version can also do graphical query designing (although you can do a limited number of designs with the free version until it runs out)

Comment: 2018 and can still say this is the best answer. Lightweight and to the point. Can even edit your stored procedures at low memory cost. The trial edition works just as good.

Answer (score 13):

I have been using [Atlantis SQL Enywhere](http://www.atlantis-interactive.co.uk/products/sqleverywhere/default.aspx), a free software, for almost 6 months and has been working really well. Works with SQL 2005 and SQL 2008 versions. I am really impressed with its features and keyboard shortcuts are similar to VS, so makes the transition really smooth to a new editor.

Some of the features that are worth mentioning:

- Intellisense that actually works when using multiple tables and joins with aliases
- Suggestion of joins when using multiple tables (reduces time on typing, really neat)
- Rich formatting of sql code, AutoIndent using Ctrl K, Ctrl D.
- Better representation of SQL plans
- Highlights variables declarations while they are used.
- Table definition on mouse hover.

All these features have saved me lot of time.

Comment: Please note that this program (as most of the others mentioned here) is just an IDE to write SQL code. You cannot use it to create or edit tables, not to mention administrative tasks. That's what the OP asks for but it can be misleading for those who come here looking for an alternative to SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: It's a nice tool, but a no-sale for me, because result grids are tabbed, not stacked as with SQL Studio, so you cannot easily compare two outputs.  One man's two cents.

Comment: "You cannot use it to create or edit tables" - what about CREATE TABLE NiceTable (id INT IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(80))); etc etc?

Answer (score 11):

[powershell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/download.mspx) + [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) :)

Comment: great suggestion, but it is easier to use tools like DbGate, SQuirreL SQL etc, more alternatives here
https://qawithexperts.com/article/sql/sql-server-management-studio-ssms-alternatives-mac-windows-l/445

Answer (score 9):

If you are already spending time in Visual Studio, then you can always use the **Server Explorer** to connect to any .Net compliant database server.

Provided you're using Professional or greater, you can create and edit tables and databases, run queries, etc.

Answer (score 4):

There is an [express version on SSMS](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en) that has considerably fewer features but still has the basics.

Answer (score 3):

vim + [dbext](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=356) :)

Answer (score 2):

Oracle has a free program called SQL Developer which will work with Microsoft SQL Server as well as Oracle & MySQL.  When accessing SQL Server, however, Oracle SQL Developer is only intended to enable an easy migration to Oracle, so your SQL Server database is essentially read-only.

Answer (score 1):

You can still install and use Query Analyzer from previous SQL Server versions.

Comment: Can you get it for free (legally) somewhere?  Or is that only for people who already owned the old version?

Comment: If you have an old version, but an old free copy of Developer Edition would do, for instance.

Comment: It doesn't work with ms sql server 2005

Comment: @Le Dorifer: I was looking for software that is better than SSMS not worse!!

Comment: Sorry - it seemed to me you were asking for lighter-weight.

Comment: I know for a fact that Gert Draper, one of the the MS SQL gurus uses Query Analyzer, but then again, he wrote it :)

Comment: Query Analyzer DOES work with SQL Server 2005 and what's interresting it has some features that SSMS does not have!!!

Comment: It **is** "better, not worse" :)

Answer (score 1):

How about Embarcadero [Rapid SQL](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/rapid-sql-xe3) Really good but kind of expensive.