# Is there a lightweight SQL gui that allows exploring databases and running SQL?

Tags: sql-server, user-interface

SQL Express is installed on the machines that I'm going to, but I'm not going to install the clunky SQL Management Studio. I just want an EXE I can run, so preferably I'd like it to be install-less.

Current options are:

1) Write one myself - not too hard, but I thought I'd check here first
2) Use the command line

Requirements:

1) Browse databases I point it at
2) Run SQL commands
3) Show output of SQL commands
4) Easily view table contents

Comment: since when is  "SQL Management Studio clunky"? mine works great...

Comment: Please see SO answers: [SQL Server Management Studio Alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170/sql-server-management-studio-alternatives)

Comment: @Mitch: I agree. Perhaps the author could clarify?

Comment: I have a bunch of low spec machines with not much space and to go onto each of them an install SQL Management Studio for 20 mins inspection seems rather a waste of time

Comment: Currently I use the command line, but I wondered if a nicer option existed... and I'm not a fan of installing more than necessary on "production" machines. Seems a silly comment really; SQL Management Studio is sizeable, and requires install. What's wrong with wanting a lightweight non-install option?

Comment: http://sqldatabasestudio.com/ works best for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There most certainly is. I found this a while back and I think it's great:
[MiniSqlQuery](http://www.codeplex.com/MiniSqlQuery)

Comment: Absolutely, completely and utterly what I wanted! If only they compiled it all into a single EXE with Reactor or ILMerge.. might just see if I can do that. Anyway, THANKS!!

Answer (score 0):

Try Navicat

http://www.navicat.com/

Its a good db admin tool.

Thanks