# sql server statement returning values 2 times

Tags: sql-server

```
select
 loginname as 'Officer',
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), visit.tmstamp, 105) as 'Date',
visit.queueno

from visit,event   where (  visit.branchno='1007'    )  
and  
(visit.wstation='1'  or visit.wstation='10'  or visit.wstation='11'  or visit.wstation='15'  or visit.wstation='2'  or visit.wstation='20'  or visit.wstation='21'  or visit.wstation='23'  or visit.wstation='24'  or visit.wstation='28'  or visit.wstation='29'  or visit.wstation='3'  or visit.wstation='30'  or visit.wstation='31'  or visit.wstation='32'  or visit.wstation='33'  or visit.wstation='4'  or visit.wstation='5'  or visit.wstation='6'  or visit.wstation='7'  or visit.wstation='8'  or visit.wstation='9'    )  and  (visit.catname='BY PASS'  or visit.catname='REG STORE'  or visit.catname='REGISTRATION'  or visit.catname='ROOM 1 to 4'  or visit.catname='ROOM A1 & A2'  or visit.catname='ROOM A3 & A4'  or visit.catname='ROOM A5-A7&A9-A11'  or visit.catname='ROOM A8-BMD'  or visit.catname='ROOM B20'  or visit.catname='ROOM B21 B23 B24'  or visit.catname='Ward Cases'    )  and  (visit.btnname='BY PASS'  or visit.btnname='REG STORE'  or visit.btnname='REGISTRATION'  or visit.btnname='ROOM 1 to 4'  or visit.btnname='ROOM A1 & A2'  or visit.btnname='ROOM A3 & A4'  or visit.btnname='ROOM A5-A7&A9-A11'  or visit.btnname='ROOM A8-BMD'  or visit.btnname='ROOM B20'  or visit.btnname='ROOM B21'  or visit.btnname='B23'  or visit.btnname='B24'  or visit.btnname='Ward Cases'  )   and (    (Day(visit.tmstamp)=1 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)      OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=2 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=3 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=4 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=5 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=6 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=7 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=8 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=9 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=10 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=11 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=13 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=14 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=15 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=16 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=17 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=18 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=19 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=20 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=21 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=22 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=23 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=24 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=25 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=26 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=27 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=28 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=29 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=30 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)       OR (DAY(visit.tmstamp)=31 AND MONTH(visit.tmstamp)=12 AND YEAR(visit.tmstamp)=2010)   ) 
and  
((loginname='Administrator')  or (loginname='121 JUDY YAP CHEO T')  or (loginname='044 Noor Faiza')  or (loginname='109 Jaya'))  
and 
(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), visit.tmstamp, 105)=CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), event.tmstamp, 105)) 
and 
(visit.loginid=event.loginid)
```

When I queried the above code, I get results twice.

If there is one one row for administrator with queueno 1005,
I got twice.

Any idea?

Comment: That probably means there are 2 events for administrator satisfying the other criteria.

[BTW, I just scrolled to the right, and that is one horrible query!]

Comment: +1 @Mitch Wheat - That's a tiny little scrollbar handle. I'm scared to scroll myself.

Comment: yea, i know.. that's horrible. Any idea to shorten it?
you can ignore that where statement. The problem doesn't lies here..

Comment: RE: "Any idea to shorten it" - Using `visit.tmstamp >= '20101201' and visit.tmstamp < '20110101'` rather than 93 different Year/Month/Day comparisons would be a start! Also you could use `In` rather than a bunch of `Or` statements on the same columns.

Comment: but is it ok to do that since tmstamp has dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one visit row with queueno 1005, then there must be 2 event rows in which loginid matches the loginid of the visit row.

Answer (score 1):

How to shorten it?

```
and visit.wstation in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 20, 21, 23, 24, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33)
and visit.tmstamp between '20110101' and  '20101201'
```

Similar things can be done with other criteria.

One good way to avoid a travesty like this is don't allow poorly written tools to generate your SQL.