# Missing bracket frustration

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL `WHERE` clause which is two pages long. I appear to be missing a bracket. Is there a way in SQL to count the right brackets and left brackets and even determine where the problem is?

The answer may be no, but I am interested to know if it is, meaning I do not have to go through hundreds of lines of code one line at a time.

Comment: try an online sql formatter: http://sqlformat.org/ this is one of many, it'll format your sql and you might be able to tell by eye where the indentation starts to go wrong.

Comment: drop your entire code block into Word or some other text editor and do a count on the bracket character.

Comment: +1 because I cannot understand the downvotes. The question is clearly stated and on-topic.

Comment: It's because all the answers and comments are for tool recommendations, and tool recommendations are off-topic.  Just use proper indentation.

Comment: LittleBobbyTables You're right!! This question is a cry for tool recommendation and is only being upvoted by people who love fishing out such recommendations!!

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: It appears that the OP does not know that Pretty Printers even exist, so a tool recommendation might only be the second step.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: Can't all questions here be answered by "just do the right thing"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an SQL pretty printer to automatically format your SQL statement. This should help you find unbalanced parenthesis.

There are many tools available for this purpose, here's an online service that I frequently use:

- http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Various other tools with SQL Server Management Studio integration can be found in this SO question:

- [Pretty Printer for T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2598915/87698)

Answer (score -2):

SQL will tell you when you parse or run the query what line the problem is on!

Comment: not really, it'll tell you that it expects a bracket, but it will likely point to the end of the query in question and say "Incorrect syntax near ')'", which doesn't point to where the bracket should be

Comment: *"SQL"*? Do you mean *"SQL Server"*?