# Free MS-SQL front end like Heidi SQL

Tags: sql-server, open-source

Yeah I know that SQL Server has got free express editions(2005/2008)
But what i want is a small simple opensource tool like Heidi Sql.
What are my options?

Regards,
naveenj

P.S: This is for my fellow Java developer who admonished me for entertaining the idea that he would install MS-SQL in his machine(lol)

Comment: It's not clear what you want - do you want an open-source *dbms* or simply an open-source *front end* to MS SQL Server (and what would be the point of that?)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170/sql-server-management-studio-alternatives for several suggestions

Comment: @Akash > Please read the title "front end"

Comment: So you're going to run a *proprietary* DBMS, but you want an *open-source* front end to it? I'm not sure I understand what would be the reason for wanting such a thing.

Comment: @Akash > My fellow developer and i am collaborating on a project spanning three four technologies. he just asked me is there a heidi sql like tool he can use to see data in the table. thats all

Comment: Just install the SQL Management Studio? Seriously, you should have more interesting things to spend your time on than creating problems for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lightest-weight query tool I know of is [QueryExPlus](http://sourceforge.net/projects/queryexplus/)

Comment: thanks ed. i liked it. suits me perfectly. supposedly made in .NET(Joseph Albahari). very light(172 kb)... glad i asked. time to pull the leg of my java guy :)

Answer (score 4):

HeidiSQL has built in support for Microsoft SQL Server since some weeks now in the latest builds. There are quite some important things left to do for me to implement to get it comparable to MySQL support, e.g. SQL export, table structure editing and the user manager which are all full of MySQL specifics. But at least you can browse SQL Server table data, see table columns and data types, and fire queries.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a front-end, have you tried [SQuirreL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

I have find it from 2005 to 2011....Still no free or open-source is good to use.
MS Management studio express is enought to use, but it is too heavy on memory.

Answer (score 0):

I recently introduced MS SQL support in HeidiSQL. There are a lot dialogs and stuff which is still MySQL related and does not work for MS SQL, but you can browse tables and data, and fire queries.

Answer (score 0):

I have use a tool called [Query Express](http://www.albahari.com/queryexpress.aspx) before and it works great. Also it is a light weight application.