# C# GUI for Databases

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am looking for programs which allows you to view a sql database in a GUI created with C#. The benefits of this would be you could create shortcuts to tables an ease of use for companies. However I can't seem to find anything on the internet about companies using a C# program to view databases.

- Have anyone used a program which does this?
- Is there a direction someone could point me in?

Many thanks.

Comment: what?? Use SSMS or similar program. Why would you create your own?

Comment: @HighCore: The OP is not asking (how) to create his or her own. That is part of why this question is not a good fit for SO.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to program anything. You have several options:

1. **SQL Server Management Studio** aka SSMS (Even SQL Server Express has it)
2. Visual Studio has a **Server Explorer** (Menu View\Server Explorer)

I think that option 1 or 2 is more than enough for you. If you want other alternatives you have [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) or [Versabanq Squel](http://versabanq.com/squel). Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170/sql-server-management-studio-alternatives) for alternatives.