# Managing SQL Server using the browser (SSMS online)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am looking for a web/cloud based solution to manage SQL Server 2012/2014 from the browser without having to install the SSMS tool. I ran across [Sql Web Admin](http://sqlwebadmin.codeplex.com/) and [myLittleAdmin](http://mylittleadmin.com/en/purchase.aspx) .

Sql Web Admin doesn't appear to be working as expected for SQL Server 2014 DBs (I wasn't able to test it against 2012) and myLittleAdmin is not a free tool.

Any one know of a way to access a SQL Server over the web? Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with the SSMS tool?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, but don't have it installed on all the computers that I work on. Also, firewall restrictions make it difficult to access servers outside the network.

Answer (score 0):

These Stackoverflow threads ([thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170/sql-server-management-studio-alternatives-to-browse-edit-tables-and-run-queries?answertab=votes#tab-top), [thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496898/decent-simple-sql-server-client/2497195#2497195)), list SSMS alternatives some portable (run off USB drive), and some written in Java. From Linqpad to Database.NET to Query Express, you should find a tool that would work for you.

Should these not work, SQL Server installs [command-line tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162816.aspx) (SQLCMD, powershell) that should get you editing/managing databases in no time

Comment: @Capt Monac, I am not necessarily looking for an installable tool. I have no issues with SSMS other than it not being able to access servers due to firewall restrictions in my network. Other tools will have similar issues, so I was looking for a browser based alternative.

Comment: Ah I see. Could you give a bit more detail on how the browser based alternative would work? What I was thinking was you could plug in a flashdrive with a "portable" SSMS alternative into a computer that is behind the firewall and voila, you have tunneled through :)